# How can I get an email notification when one on one meetings I calendar are "declined"?

Tags: google-workspace, google-calendar, notifications

Google calendar question. I need to periodically meet with senior leaders one on one. These meetings are difficult to keep and are frequently "declined" in favor of other urgent priorities. I do not want to be constantly checking if they are still on or declined and frequently I discover they've be declined the day before or day of when I'm reviewing my calendar and preparing. It might have been declined weeks earlier but I just didn't realize. I'd like an email when these meetings are declined so I can get busy rescheduling them. It would be great to condition these notifications by name or even by meeting size and regardless if I set the original meeting or the executive did.

Comment: Google calendar, by default, informs you when meetings are accepted or declined. Check your spam folder.

Comment: To clarify: Are you using the "normal" Google Calendar, or are you working within Google Apps (for Work)?

Comment: Nothing in the spam folder (could be for a number of reasons). Are you suggesting  some sort of filter approach to pull up the ones of interest and keep them in the email and out of wherever they are going now?Google Apps for Education

Comment: No, just wondering why you're not already receiving cancellation notices. I'm afraid I don't have a Google Apps account, so probably can't help you there.

Answer (score 1):

These directions apply to both consumer (@gmail.com) and enterprise Google accounts.

To ensure you are configured to receive email notifications when events on a calendar are canceled please follow the steps below. If you have created additional calendars beyond the primary calendar, you may need to repeat these steps for each calendar.

- In a computer's web browser go to calendar.google.com and sign into your account if you aren't already
- Click the gear icon in the upper right
- Select Settings from the Drop down menu
- Select Calendars in the top menu
- Click Edit notifications for the calendar you wish to check the settings for. This will usually by your primary calendar, and it will usually be named after you
- Check the box for Email on the line marked Canceled events. You may wish to review the settings for the other types of notifications on this page
- Be sure to click the Save button
- Click Back to calendar

Note that these notification emails are from the calendar service to you, not from the person that canceled the event. These emails will be sent to you regardless of if the person cancelling the event decides to notify you of the cancelation or not.